How to get rid of the bottom padding in a framed "figure"?
I'm doing this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tcolorbox}[frame empty, colback=gray]
hello world!
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

The bottom white padding is annoying (because it's not equal to the left, right and top paddings):

How can I get rid of it?

Add after skip=0pt:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tcolorbox}[frame empty, colback=gray, after skip=0pt]
hello world!
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


